# Average Stacking in MLR over responses, when two base learners disagree

Tags: r, ensemble-learning, mlr

I was using the 'average' stacking method to stack two base learners in MLR. It looks something like this:

```
stacked.lrns[[1]] = makeStackedLearner(base.lrns,
                                       method = 'average', 
                                       predict.type = 'response')
```

My question is:
If I have two base learners and one predicts outcome 1 and the other outcome 0 in a binary classification context. How does the average method compute the stacked response, since the average should be (1+0)/2 = 0.5?

Note, that I have to stack responses and not probabilistic estimates in this particular case.

I would be grateful for any insights you could give me into how the algorithm decides in these cases.

Best wishes,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The majority vote is taken in this case.

See code of the function `predictLearner.StackedLearner` in https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/StackedLearner.R:

```
return(factor(apply(probs, 1L, computeMode), td$class.levels))
```

It is not well documented at the moment.

Best regards,
Philipp

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am sorry, could you clarify what "majority" you are referring to? Since it cannot be the majority of the two classifiers voting against each other for this particular sample (implying no majority: 1:1), at least in my example, when I only stack two classifiers. Do you mean the majority vote across samples (like  the prior in a Bayesian approach, i.e. the majority class in the training data)?

Comment: If it is 1:1, a value is randomly taken, see the 'BBmisc::computeMode' function for more details.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!